# Operator '+' always concats the value instead of adding

Tags: javascript

I have started learning Javascript recently and I am trying to create a script used to calculate a set of user input numbers. I use a function to give a prompt to the user and get the value from the user. Then I use another function to take the prompt input and add it to my own value. But the result is always a set of continuous values. My code is the following one, please help.

```
<body>
    <p>
        Click below to calculate a value.
    </p>

    <button onclick='myfunc()'>Calculate</button>

    <p id='demo'></p>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function getvalue() {
                                var foo = prompt('Enter a number');
                                return(foo);
                            }
        function myfunc() {

                            var a = getvalue();
                            var x = a + 2;
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
                          }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `return Number(foo)`

Comment: `prompt` returns a string. So for example: `"1" + 2` would be `"12"`. You will want to convert it into a number.

Comment: i think `getValue` in your case is returning a `String`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @MatteusBrevik pointed out that I use the **parseInt** to return numerical value of the **getValue** block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use parseInt()
>   
> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Either you can use it inside your function or outside like following.

```
    function getvalue() {
                            var foo = prompt('Enter a number');
                            parseInt(foo); //Parse string to integer
                        }
```

OR

```
    function myfunc() {

                        var a = parseInt(getvalue()); //Parse string to integer
                        var x = a + 2;
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
                      }
```

Dont forget to do validation  (to make sure it's an integer) of the prompt output in your program !

Answer (score 0):

All inputs from `prompt` are treated as a string.  You need to specify the var type to be a number (it can be an integer - int - or decimal - double or float). To parse the value just use parseInt, parseDouble, parseFloat.

Difference between double and float is the decimal accuracy.

```js
function getvalue() {
        var foo = prompt('Enter a number');
        return parseInt(foo); // also try parseDouble for decimal values
    }

function myfunc() {
    var a = getvalue();
    var x = a + 2;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myfunc()">Test</button>
<br/>
<p>
The Value is: <span id="demo"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string into a number with the `+` operator :

```
function getvalue() {
    //        v Here is where the magic is taking place       
    var foo = +prompt('Enter a number');
    return(foo);
}
function myfunc() {
    var a = getvalue();
    var x = a + 2;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```